# jclouds openstack create instance

Tags: java, eclipse, openstack, jclouds

I recently installed jclouds to use with eclipse to create a project in java to communicate with openstack. Does anyone know if there is a way to create an instance from a snapshot or using default parameters (ovf image ). I would appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Comment: A snapshot is a term usually used in block storage (aka volumes). Do you mean booting from a snapshot volume? Or do you mean booting from a "snapshot" of an image taken from an instance? What do you mean by "default parameters"? Can you give me an example of what you want to do using the OpenStack nova command line client?

Comment: of course. i want something similar to  "nova boot ..... " command of openstack. i found the NovaClient interface with the CreateServer method , but something tells me that it is not i am looking for. Can you help me plz ? i am lost. to be more exact i wanna boot new instances from jclouds using Eclipse

Comment: To be even more specific this is my very simple code:

private void createNode() {
  /*
   * String a1 = "test";
   *  String a2 ="de30a390-ad7d-4dea-8917-ab3ab696f8";
   *  String a3 = "2";
   * org.jclouds.openstack.nova.options.CreateServerOptions[] a4="";
   * System.out.println("Creating Server");    akis.createServer(a1, a2,a3,a4); 
System.out.println("Server Created");
   */
  akis.getServer(bc14c5b3-9ef1-4c68-87d4-5db3f146dbd2);
 }

Comment: What version of jclouds are you using? There is no such class as NovaClient. Do you perhaps mean CloudServersClient? Also there is no org.jclouds.openstack.nova.options.CreateServerOptions. There is org.jclouds.cloudservers.options.CreateServerOptions and org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.options.CreateServerOptions. Are you using one of those?

Comment: Finally i figured it out. It is org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.options.CreateServerOptions that i had to use in order to create a new instance. Everett thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you post the code you used as an answer below to help the next person who finds this question? Thanks.

Comment: of course. here it is.

private void createServers() {
  for (String zone : zones) {
   ServerApi serverApi = nova.getApi().getServerApiForZone(zone);
   CreateServerOptions sv = CreateServerOptions.Builder.adminPass("test");
   ServerCreated newServer = serverApi.create("test", "ab8fbee6-4907-4e59-ba77-471362bc8200", "2", sv);
   System.out.println("Servers in " + zone);
   TemplateOptions.Builder.authorizePublicKey("/home/christopher/id_rsa.pub.pub");
  }
  
 }

Answer (score -1):

Try [OpenStack4j](http://openstack4j.com).  Jcloud is only a high level basic API for OpenStack since it supports many other clouds. Example using OpenStack4j

```
// Create a Server Model Object
Server server = Builders.server()
                    .name("Ubuntu 2")
                    .flavor("flavorId")
                    .image("imageId")
                    .addPersonality("/etc/motd", "Welcome to the new VM! Restricted access only")
                    .build();

 // Boot the Server
 Server server = os.compute().servers().boot(server);
```